# Storing select option value into PHP variable

Tags: php, html

```
 <select align="center" type=text name="Class" class="Class">
   <option>
     select something
   </option>

   <?php
      $dropmenu = array_values(array_filter(array_unique($dbarray)));
      for($index = 0; $index < count($dropmenu); $index++)
      {
        echo "<option value='".$dropmenu[$index]."'>".$dropmenu[$index]."</option>";
      }
   ?>
 </select>
```

Above code generates select box menu based on `$dropmenu` array. Whenever user select something and click the submit button I want to store its option value into `PHP variable` without redirecting to new page with `$_POST[]`.

Purpose is to check up every checkbox from DB which user selected. Is PHP able to save values to variables without any redirection?

Comment: you can use post the current script then you can store it on global variable that will available after the request is done

Comment: @Jerson You mean `$_POST` can be done in single page without any redirection?